Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 127
I'm getting this error:
Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 127

when I perform firebase deploy --only functions from inside my functions directory.
I have no idea why it is happening. I have tried npm install, npm install -g firebase-tools, changing "lint": "eslint .", to "lint": "eslint", and checking my node version (it's 18) but still the same problem.
Here is my package.json if its of any use:
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^12.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

Does anyone know how to fix the deployment error?

Could you share your 'firebase.jsonfile contents? It looks like the Firebase CLI is encountering an error when runningpredeploy` script, which is causing the deployment to exit.
